# Live Templates not working anymore with Resharper 6

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

I upgraded to Resharper v6 and since then, the live templates don't work anymore.
If I type a template name (like prop) and then tab, the template name is just removed, and nothing happens.

If I try to insert a new class, there's only the basic text with placeholders, and the template isn't run on it.

I tried to uninstall resharper and reinstall from scratch to no avail.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried to disable all the other extensions I have installed (power command and power tools), but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had to uninstall and reinstall the whole visual studio.
Everything's back to normal now, but couldn't find any shortcuts.

No idea what broke in the first place.